# MVVM Database Child_Update() not updateing

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm, updates

Ok here is the deal. using my Model to raise the Child_Update() Method. I know it is not good but im just learing right now. Now i given my Business class as Parameter to Change the already given rows. 
It's doin everything fine without any error Messages and there is also no null variable but it's not changing anything in the database.

here i'm using the selectedIndex to choose the right items to update

```
public void ExecuteAngestellte(object obj)
{
    try
    {
       _selectedIndex.Child_Update(new Farbe { FarbauswahlNr = SelectedIndex.FarbauswahlNr, Kurztext = SelectedIndex.Kurztext, Ressource = SelectedIndex.Ressource, Vari1 = SelectedIndex.Vari1, Vari2 = SelectedIndex.Vari2 });

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

and here's the child update

```
public void Child_Update(Farbe data)
{
    using (var ctx =Csla.Data.ObjectContextManager<TestDBEntities>.GetManager(EntitiesDatabase.Name))
    {
        var objectStateManager = ctx.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
        var _data = new Datenbank.Farbe();

        _data.FarbauswahlNr = data.FarbauswahlNr;
        _data.Kurztext = data.Kurztext;
        _data.Ressource = data.Ressource;
        _data.Var1 = data.Vari1;
        _data.Vari2 = data.Vari2;

        ctx.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

thx for help

Comment: if you place a breakpoint in the Child_Update function, does it ever get to the SaveChanges?

Comment: yes it is gettin to the SaveChanges()

Comment: and btw. my insert is working fine

Comment: not sure how the insert is working because it looks like the `_data` is not is separate from the data context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I can tell, your _data is not part of the datacontext

I am not sure what the variables all mean so here is a simple update I use for a single record with entity framework

```
public void UpdateTable(int idRecord, YourContext Context)
{ 
    MyRecord = Context.MyTable.Find(idRecord);
    myRecord.Column = "New Value";
    Context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

so I think you need to do:

```
 var MyData = ctx.ObjectContext.TableName.Find(id)
```

I am assuming you are using entity framework.  Does this help?